# Architectural advice to developing Service Portal Application

Tags: servicenow

I am new in Service Now platform, developing a custom app using the service portal and I am looking for some architectural advice from experts.

My storyline is my service is gonna serve different companies as per their requirements by easy codebase maintenance. for example, I am having a base app which has some concrete requirements that fit for all companies, but there will be some other features for company specific, like *feature A for company A*, *feature B for company B* and so on. So my initial plan was like classic software development that is to have a single codebase using git that will have multiple feature branches that will deploy to multiple instances. But sometimes some situation where I might need to merge the branches that is not possible now. My question here *is there any alternative way to do that?* Other possible scenarios here is *should I go with a single instance with ACL based data separation?* (but that not feels scalable to me cause the amount of the data will be huge after some time) or *is that possible to apply regular SAAS architecture like multitenancy(single app with multiple databases) with some configuration wise feature separation?*

Thanks in Advance.